# How to use bitoperations correctly in C

Tags: c, enums

i'm a beginner at C and i have some problems with the bitoperations. Already searched for explenations of bitoperations and i cant detect any mistake in my code.

The task is to serialize and deserialize data from two enum datatypes into a 16 bit int value.

```
typedef enum {
Stop = 0,
Start = 1,
Finish = 5,
Fail = 255
} Status;

typedef enum {
One = 1,
Fifteen = 15,
Last = 255
} Numbers;
```

Data from the enum Status should be saved in the low Byte and data from the enum Numbers should be saved in the high Byte.
So my serialize functions looks like this:

```
void serialize(Status s, Numbers n, short int* data) {
*data = (unsigned) n<<8;
*data = (unsigned) (*data|s);
}
```

my deserialize function looks like this:

```
void deserialize(unsigned short int data, Status* s, Numbers* n) {
*s = (unsigned) data<<8;
*s = (unsigned) *s>>8;
*n = (unsigned) data>>8;
}
```

The problem now is that when i run this testfunction it always calls fail.

```
void testSD(Status s, Numbers n) {
unsigned short int data;
Status s2;
Numbers n2;
serialize(s, n, &data);
deserialize(data, &s2, &n2);
if(s2 == s && n2 == n) {
printf("succsess \n");
}
else {
printf("fail \n");
}
}
```

The testfunction is correct because i got that from my professor.

Comment: You're sure `short int* data` is supposed to be signed? I'm kinda doubting it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `serialize` function, the data pointed by `data` will be like

```
+--------+--------+
|nnnnnnnn|ssssssss|
+--------+--------+
```

Then, the `deserialize` function works like this:

`*s = (unsigned) data<<8;`

```
     +--------+--------+--------+
*s = |nnnnnnnn|ssssssss|00000000|
     +--------+--------+--------+
```

`*s = (unsigned) *s>>8;`

```
     +--------+--------+
*s = |nnnnnnnn|ssssssss|
     +--------+--------+
```

`*n = (unsigned) data>>8;`

```
     +--------+
*n = |nnnnnnnn|
     +--------+
```

Therefore, the value of `*s` become wrong.

`deserialize` should be something like this:

```
void deserialize(unsigned short int data, Status* s, Numbers* n) {
    *s = (unsigned) data & 0xff;
    *n = (unsigned) data>>8;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot now i see my failure. this helped a lot. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your deserialize function is not correct.

Imagine that status=5, number=1.

The value in data would be

0105  (hexidecimal)

In deserialize, you get the number as n>>8, so the lower part gets shifted out and you have a value of 1, which is correct.

For status, you are currently shifting it by 8 so it is 010500 (hex) and then shifting it back down 0150 (hex)

What you really want is just the lower 8 bits, which typically would be done by ANDing the value with 0xFF.

ie: 0105 & 0xFF = 05

So change the deserialize part of the for status to:

*s = data & 0xFF;